# Spartacus Internationalization is not working

Tags: angular, internationalization, spartacus-storefront

I am using Spartacus 4.3

**spartacus-configuration.module.ts**:

```
provideConfig(<I18nConfig>{
      i18n: {
        backend: {
          loadPath: '/src/assets/translations/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        },
        chunks: translationChunksConfig,
        fallbackLang: 'en',
      },
    }),
```

It doesn't work for any component in the storefront.

In my components' modules I have imported I18nModule.
In the templates I use the `| cxTranslate` pipe

In the console I have a lot of warning messages like this:
*Translation key missing 'common.home' in the chunk 'common'*

I followed the instructions here https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/i18n/

in my /src/assets/translations/ folder I have an /en/ folder structured just like the /node_modules/@spartacus/assets/i18n-assets/en folder

Answer (score 3):

Please notice, that the output folder for assets after compilation is `assets`, not `src/assets`. Your configuration should look like this:

```
provideConfig(<I18nConfig>{
   i18n: {
     backend: {
         loadPath: 'assets/translations/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
     },
     chunks: translationChunksConfig,
     fallbackLang: 'en',
   },
}),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this as well and it's still not working

Comment: @Andrei Thank you for your response. Can you provide more details? Is there still the same issue?